# Laravel: Send files via Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to upload files using Ajax and Laravel, every time I try to upload one it returns empty. This is the method in Laravel:

```
public function save_vehicles(Request $request){
    $files=$request->file('input_file_vehicles');
    return response()->json(['File: '.$files]);
    \Log::info($files);
}
```

And this is the Ajax function:

```
var save_vehicles=function(input_file){
  var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("input_file_vehicles",input_file);
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        contentType:  false,
        data: formData,
        url: '/save/vehicles'
    });
}
```

The result from this call is:

> "File: "

It returns empty.

Comment: please post your form as well

Comment: input_file_vehicles != input_file_vehicle (you're sending "input_file_vehicles" over AJAX, but expecting "input_file_vehicle" in your Laravel file)

Comment: Originally is input_file_vehiculo, but I changed it before posting here.

Comment: Use the browser dev tools to check if you are sending the file input

Comment: @GabrielAlejandro Honestly, it's alright that variable names not be translated :)

Answer (score 1):

jquery code

```
var save_vehicles=function(input_file){
    var formData = new FormData($('#formElem'));
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        contentType:  false,
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
    },
        data: formData,
        url: '/save/vehicles'
    });
}
```

Laravel Code

```
$destinationPath = 'path/th/save/file/';
$image = $request->file('input_file_vehicles');
$name =  $image->getClientOriginalName();
$extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
$file_name =  $name;
$image->move($destinationPath,$file_name);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are appending `input_file_vehicles` but trying to access `input_file_vehicle` in the controller method.

Comment: Sorry, originally is input_file_vehiculo, but I changed it before posting here. That's not the actual mistake, thank you for the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Your form should look like this

```
<form action="/" name="myForm" id="myForm" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
</form>
```

Comment: This does not matter when using AJAX. In fact, you don't even need a form wrapper.