# Unable to get ajax response using jquery(laravel 5.3)

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I am working in laravel. i have form data and a file to submit with ajax in DB.

Its creating but not return any response in success method here is my code

```
$('#student-frm').submit(function(){
    $("#processing").removeAttr("style", "display:none");
    var form_data = $("#student-frm").serialize();
    form_data.append("file", $("#import").get(0).files[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/student-management/emails',
        type: 'POST',
        data: form_data,
        success: function(result) {
            alert(result);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

i have dropdowns in form to insert one by one or attach file so im using `form_data.append().`

**if i remove  this below line of code from above method it works fine.**

```
form_data.append("file", $("#import").get(0).files[0]);
```

I am returning from Controller as

```
return 'success';
```

It returns in browser

Please Help what is this issue

Thanks

Comment: You are saying because of `form_data.append("file", $("#import").get(0).files[0]);` line you are not able to get the ajax response ?

Comment: yes if i remove this line it return response

Comment: What error display in console?

Comment: check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44638402/laravel-send-files-via-ajax/44638448#44638448

Comment: @bluemoon check my answer given below

Answer (score 1):

The issue is `searialze` and `FormData` are two different things. You cannot append file to `searialze` data. In that case you need `FormData`. Use it like:

```
var form_data= new FormData();
```

and append what ever data you want in it.

Ex:

```
var file_data = $('#import').prop('files')[0];
var form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append('file', file_data);
// append file to form, in the same way you can append more data in key, value pair
```

This is just like append the html element into a `form` and than submit that form to the server.

On the server side you can get the appended `file` like:

```
$_FILES['file']
```

Comment: please can you explain a little where and how to append using new formData

Comment: should i use this after searialze form data?

Comment: please tell me if i can use alternate method for file post.. its not working for me

Comment: You cannot use searialze with formdata

Comment: What is your exact requirement? You want to upload file as well as some data to the server ?

Comment: yes exactly both data and file. sometimes will be only data and sometimes file with data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147343/discussion-between-mayank-pandeyz-and-blue-moon).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working code :
jquery code :

```
$('#student-frm').submit(function(){
    $("#processing").removeAttr("style", "display:none");
    var formData = new FormData($('#student-frm'));
    $.ajax({
        url: '/student-management/emails',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        success: function(result) {
            alert(result);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Laravel Code :

```
$destinationPath = 'path/th/save/file/';
$image = $request->file('input_file');
$name =  $image->getClientOriginalName();
$file_name =  $name;
$image->move($destinationPath,$file_name);
```

Comment: what will be formElem in 2nd line??

Comment: `var formData = new FormData($('#formElem'));` are you talking about this line? `$('#formElem')` this is the id of form

Answer (score 0):

add these two line in your ajax code as you are sending the files using formdata, so it is necessary to add these lines

```
 processData: false,
 contentType:  false,
```

So your ajax will be like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/student-management/emails',
    type: 'POST',
    data: form_data,
    processData: false,
    contentType:  false,
    success: function(result) {
        alert(result);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use form data for uploading :

```
$('#student-frm').submit(function(){
    $("#processing").removeAttr("style", "display:none");
    var form = $('form')[0]; 
    var formData = new FormData(form);

    // Attach file
    formData.append('file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]); 

     $.ajax({
            url: '/student-management/emails',
            type: 'POST',
            data: form_data,
            success: function(result) {
                alert(result);
            }
        });
        return false;
 });
```

And get file from request in Laravel Controller

```
if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
    $file = $request->file('file');
}
```